# How to get the value from a attribute name of a class in python?

Tags: python-3.x, attributes

I would want to get all the values from the attributes from a class so If my program gets an error, I can look the json files and see the values from the classes and then see the problem.

```
class Example:
     def __init__(self, x, y):
          self.x = x
          self.y = y

e = Example(1, 2)

data = []
for attribute_name in dir(e):
    attribute = getattr(b, attribute_name)
    if not callable(attribute):
        data.append({"name":attribute_name, "value":attribute.value})

print(data)
```

What I want:

```
[{"name":"x", "value":1}, {"name":"y", "value":2}]
```

Comment: `getattr` should work. Does it not? Why do you do `"value": attribute.value` instead of `"value": attribute`? What's your question?

Comment: Typo: `getattr(b, attribute_name)`. `b` is undefined. Did you mean `getattr(e, attribute_name)`?

Comment: In addition to the `callable` check, you should also check if the attribute is a dunder attribute, like `__dict__`, `__doc__`, or `__module__`. You can do this with `attribute_name.startswith('__')`

Comment: Right, ```getattr``` works, my question was How to get the value of the attribute because I wasn't getting a value from it, i was getting a lot of functions, at the end it was a mistake mine, I had a variable in the wrong place. The ```attribute.value``` was like a example of what I wanted. Thx anyway.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have 3 mistakes.

1. As Pranav Hosangadi points out, you have a typo with `getattr(b, attribute_name)`. It should be `getattr(e, attribute_name)`.
2. You call `attribute.value` unnecessarily. Simply `attribute` is sufficient.
3. Using just `if not callable(attribute)` will output `[{'name': '__module__', 'value': '__main__'}, {'value': 1, 'name': 'x'}, {'name': 'y', 'value': 2}]`. `__module__` isn't something you want, so check for `__` in the attribute name in addition.

With that said, below is the full corrected code:

```py
class Example:
     def __init__(self, x, y):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y

e = Example(1, 2)

data = []
for attribute_name in dir(e):
    attribute = getattr(e, attribute_name)
    if "__" not in attribute_name and not callable(attribute):
        data.append({"name": attribute_name, "value": attribute})

print(data)
# Prints [{'name': 'x', 'value': 1}, {'name': 'y', 'value': 2}]
```

Comment: I think the `callable` check is also relevant because it prevents writing attributes that are functions.

Comment: @PranavHosangadi True; it doesn't matter in this case since there are no functions, but I'll add that.

Comment: "In this case" is hardly relevant when this case is clearly a [mre]